# Closing a runnable JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I have this Runnable window:

```
 EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        op = new JOptionPane("Breaktime",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        dialog = op.createDialog("Break");
        dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true); 
        dialog.setModal(true);
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);      
        dialog.setVisible(true);
     }
 });
```

Is it possible that I can have a timer here to close this within 1 or 2 minutes instead of clicking the OK button?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the trick would be to get the `Timer` started before you call `setVisible`...

```
public class AutoClose02 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AutoClose02();
    }

    private Timer timer;
    private JLabel label;
    private JFrame frame;

    public AutoClose02() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JOptionPane op = new JOptionPane("Breaktime", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                final JDialog dialog = op.createDialog("Break");
                dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                dialog.setModal(true);
                dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

                // Wait for 1 minute...
                timer = new Timer(60 * 1000, new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        dialog.dispose();
                    }
                });
                timer.setRepeats(false);
                // You could use a WindowListener to start this
                timer.start();

                dialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: the should I set the timer close?

Comment: I'm sorry, didn't catch that

Comment: 60 * 1000 = 1min right, how about 2mins 120 * 1000?

Comment: Yep, 1 second = 1000 milliseconds, 1 minute = 60 seconds = 60000 milliseconds and so on and so forth...you could also use 2 * 60 * 1000