# Java: How to put timer in JOptionPane that's imported?

Tags: java, swing, timer, joptionpane

I import `javax.swing.*;` and have a JOptionPane:

```
String meny = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What's the answer?").trim();
```

I want this window to close after the amount of seconds the user inserts:

```
String time = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How much time").trim();

int timer1 = Integer.parseInt(time);
```

I do not know how to do this. Should I do something like this?

```
if (timer1 == 0) {
meny.setVisible(false);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's "complicated", have a look at [this for an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22979504/closing-a-runnable-joptionpane/22979571#22979571)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
            JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane("Message", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(null, "Title");
            dialog.setModal(false);
            dialog.setVisible(true);

            new Timer(10000, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    dialog.setVisible(false);
                }
            }).start();
```