# Java static window with dynamic content

Tags: java, swing, dialog, window, joptionpane

I have a streaming application which fetches data from Twitter. I'd like to show some of the statistics that I compute into a real-time window.
I'd like to know if it's possible to create a static window with dynamic content (maybe with JOptionPane?). By dynamic I mean something that is updated from time to time.
Example:

[image]

The window has only the "close" button. The number refreshes itself every tot x seconds.

Any help is appreciated, I haven't found anything helpful on the Internet.

Comment: "a static window with dynamic content"  Isn't this what every app ever created is?  I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: By dynamic I mean something that refreshes, while the windows stays where it is

Comment: Don't all apps do that?  If I open VLC to watch a video, the window doesn't move around the screen.

Comment: No, it's not what I mean. I'm gonna edit the question with a pic to make it clearer

Comment: @SteveSmith question updated, what do you think?

Comment: It's just a window showing content.  What is the specific problem you are facing?

Comment: Do I have to close the window each time the content is refreshed, or can I just change the content without closing the window? That's the real point of the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146893/discussion-between-steve-smith-and-sirdan).

Comment: If latency is minimal, try this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44417958/230513); otherwise consider `SwingWorker`, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4637725/230513).

Answer (score 0):

I do not really understand your "static window"...

However you can add a background thread, or even a timer to update the contents of your window.

Comment: I mean a window that once opened, it never goes away. It just updates the content.

Comment: What do you mean "never goes away"?  Even if the user wants to close it?

Comment: Possibly a "stay-on-top" window?

Comment: Like this?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297938/always-on-top-windows-with-java

Comment: I don't think it's about what you suggested @usagimiyamoto, check the question again, I updated it with a picture

Comment: That is just what i was referring to: A window, and a timer that refreshes the contents...